# Pandas Data Frame in Python. Proportions and Transpose

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame in Pandas. The idea is to generate an additional data frame IDs based on the proportion of the variable TYPE, transposing it into columns. Any help is appreciated!

```
d = {'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'TYPE': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df


    ID   A       B       C
    1   0.30    0.40    0.3
    2   0.25    0.75    0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with parameter `normalize=True` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['TYPE'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
TYPE     A     B    C
ID                   
1     0.30  0.40  0.3
2     0.25  0.75  0.0
```

Then if necessary column from `index`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID     A     B    C
0   1  0.30  0.40  0.3
1   2  0.25  0.75  0.0
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the exact answer I was looking for :)